# 404, url not found when registering with router.urls

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have declared a viewset like this:

```
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
    queryset = School.objects.all()
```

I used routers to register urls, like this:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'schools', SchoolViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

I expected this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/schools/1/` with GET, but surprisingly is giving me 404, the same example works in docs, but not for me,
please tell me whats wrong with the code.

EDIT:
I should have inherited ModelViewSet; that sorted it out.

Comment: Are you certain you have a `school` with that ID?

Comment: We might need more information. Do you have an entry with that ID? Do the other endpoints of the viewset work? (List, create, ...)

Comment: Could you make sure your pasted code is correct ? What's here strictly won't work. `ViewSet` can't be registered without a `base_name`

Comment: base_name is not mandatory, i have checked